# Type for a string literal

Tags: c++

I have a type

```
char [6] const&
```

Is this:

```
1. Reference to a const array of 6 chars
2. Reference to an array of 6 const chars
3. const reference to an array of 6 chars
```

Would a type like `const pointer to an array of 6 chars` be meaningful or is it just meaningful to talk references to these? I got confused about all these things.

Comment: Who's asking these questions? Why would you want to associate with them?

Comment: And you omitted number 4: "It's not a valid declarator"

Comment: That's the type given to me by the compiler, type for a string literal like `"Hello"`.

Comment: Then the compiler has a quality of implementation issue. But to be frank, I'd be surprised if it really is part of the compiler output, verbatim.

Comment: @meguli, https://godbolt.org/g/HYoqoL

Comment: @StoryTeller I feel an innocent "I use Borland compiler" comment incoming.

Comment: Not a verbatim output as it seems from @chris. My very bad.

Comment: So how did you get that type name?

Comment: I got the code from another question, while C++11 version was working at runtime and was not verbatim compiler output, C++17 version was compile-time.  I had mistaken these two. For the record, C++17 version says the type is `const char (&)[6]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 4. invalid syntax for a type declaration
 5. something you shouldn't worry about
 6. 4 & 5
```

6. The correct answer is 6.

Comment: Smart approach.

Comment: That type is returned by the compiler, as the type of a string literal of length 5.

Comment: @meguli what do you mean it is returned by the compiler? And what compiler?